# extracting one bit of data from json result

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to extract one bit of data from a JSON array when loaded with CURL. Its loads it fine from what I can tell if I echo the results but when I to get the postal_town I just keep coming across a blank???? My PHP code :

```
  $url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.406822,-1.519693&sensor=true";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $response_a = json_decode($response, true);
    $town = $response_a['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['types']['postal_town'];

    echo $town;
```

And a sample of the JSON result is:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Ringway Rudge",
               "short_name" : "A4053",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Coventry",
               "short_name" : "Coventry",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Coventry",
               "short_name" : "Coventry",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "West Midlands",
               "short_name" : "West Midlands",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "England",
               "short_name" : "England",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
```

Comment: I don't see a postal_town key in your JSON...

Comment: "types" : [ "postal_town" ] its there 3rd one down

Comment: That's not a key though, that's a value.

Comment: oh? All i want is to set to set the value of is to $city. Sorry maybe I worded it wrong

Comment: I don't think it's how you worded it, it's how you're attempting to access it.  You're attempting to access postal_town as a key and somehow expecting that to return something?  But postal_town isn't a key, it's a value in the types array.

Comment: How shall I access it? I have tried several different ways but to no avail? Am I going about it all wrong?

Comment: Yes, you can't access it by key, you'd need to use something like array_filter to filter the array down by the contents of the types array.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick, did what Devon said to do, thanks

```
   $result = @file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.406822,-1.519693&sensor=true" );
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        //manage exception from file_get_contents call
    } else {
        $geocodedinfo = json_decode($result);
        if ($geocodedinfo->status == "OK") {
            $town = "";
            foreach ($geocodedinfo->results[0]->address_components as $addrcomps) {
                if ( $addrcomps->types[0] == 'postal_town')
                    $town = $addrcomps->long_name;           
            }
        }
    }


    echo $town;
```